# Wpf ContextMenu MenuItem Header Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu, datacontext

I have a ContextMenu defined in a control this way...

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding CurrentLang.CmenuItemUnLockUser}"/>            
    </ContextMenu>
```

CurrentLang.CmenuItemUnLockUser is a string.

The DataContext is defined in the xaml (and working...):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <admin:AdminViewModel/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
```

The BlockedUserContextMenu is used in a DataGrid and defined as:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgridCases"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CasesCollection"
          ...>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowContextMenu}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

CasesCollection is an ObservableCollection of CaseObject objects, i can see in the output window that can't found CurrentLang.CmenuItemUnLockUser in the CaseObject, so, the issue is related to the datacontext...

How can i specify the right datacontext?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be as simple as `<ContextMenu DataContext={Binding}...`?

Comment: Where is the CurrentLang property defined? In the AdminViewModel class or in the CaseObject class?

Comment: @DonBoitnott, no it doesn't works... Thanks!

Comment: @mm8 CurrentLang is defined in the AdminViewModel, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `CurrentLang` property is defined in the `AdminViewModel` class, you can't bind to it directly from the `DataGridRow`. That's because the `DataContext` of the `DataGridRow` is the `CaseObject` for that particular row.

What you could do is to bind the `Tag` property of the `DataGridRow` to the `AdminViewModel` using a `{RelativeSource}` binding:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

...and then bind to the `CurrentLang` of the `AdminViewModel` using the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="RowContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.CurrentLang.CmenuItemUnLockUser, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: So smart! I usually think about tag as a string, but it's an object... Thanks!